# Cycloning in trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have table like this

```
 id | col1 | col2
```

I need write trigger so: after inserting or updating column `col1` , I need insert (update) same value in column `col2`

This is my trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  upd () RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
   BEGIN 
       UPDATE mytable SET
       col2 =  col1;
       RETURN NULL;
   END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and this is self trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd()
```

This not works because happening cycloning at `UPDATE` event, right?

What is right syntax for do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@a_horse and @David have already pointed out the superior solution with a GIN index for your case.

But one more thing concerning the answer to your original question: since you only need the trigger `after inserting or updating column col1`, you should be using the more specific event [**`UPDATE OF ...`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html), available since Postgres 9.0:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF col1 ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd()
```

This way you could even prevent endless loops / recursion ("cycloning" as you call it) in an `AFTER` trigger. But it's still generally more sensible to use a `BEFORE` trigger, like @a_horse already provided.

Comment: `UPDATE OF` really helps me, thanks. But  `BEFORE` trigger not works, `AFTER` works, why? what is wrong in my trigger function?

Comment: @OTARIKI: Hard to say. One would need the complete picture. Maybe other triggers interfere? Did you try the improved trigger function a_horse provided?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an update, just assign the value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  upd () RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$body$
   BEGIN 
      new.col2 := to_tsvector(new.col1);
      RETURN new;
   END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And you need to do this in the **before** trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd()
```

**Edit**:

As @DavidAldridge has pointed out in his comment, it's probably easier to index the ts_vector() directly:

```
create index col1_vector 
    on mytable (to_tsvector(col1)) 
    using gin;
```

A query using

```
where to_tsvector(col1) = '...'
```

would then be able to use that index.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the value for col2 is deterministically dependent only on that of col1 then col2 shouldn't be stored at all.

Comment: `col2` is for saving `tsvector` data, original data is saved in `col1`, (For full text search).  But in question, for clearing, I dont write this.

Comment: Have you looked at creating a gin index on ts_vector(col1)?