# Joins around if statement for PostgreSQL trigger function

Tags: postgresql, join, triggers, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have a table `a` with 3 triggers that insert, update, or delete corresponding rows in `b` whenever a row in `a` is inserted, updated, or deleted. All 3 triggers use the same trigger function `p`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    -- INSERT INTO b ...
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    -- UPDATE b ...
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    -- DELETE FROM b ...
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER i AFTER INSERT ON a FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE p ();
CREATE TRIGGER u AFTER UPDATE ON a FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE p ();
CREATE TRIGGER d AFTER DELETE ON a FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE p ();
```

`a` also has a foreign key `a1` into `c` (with primary key `c1`), and I would like to alter `p` in such a way that it enters the `IF`/`ELSIF` branches also depending on a column `c2` in `c`: if that joined column changed, enter the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` branches; if it stayed the same, enter the `UPDATE` branch. In effect, something like this:

```
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') OR ((TG_OP = 'UPDATE') AND (oldC.c2 <> newC.c2)) THEN
    -- ...
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') OR (oldC.c2 = newC.c2) THEN
    -- ...
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') OR ((TG_OP = 'UPDATE') AND (oldC.c2 <> newC.c2)) THEN
    -- ...
  ELSE
    -- ...
  END IF;
```

where `oldC` and `newC` would result from joins similar to these (with approx. syntax):

```
SELECT oldC.* FROM a, c AS oldC WHERE OLD.a1 = c.c1;
SELECT newC.* FROM a, c AS newC WHERE NEW.a1 = c.c1;
```

So what is needed in effect are two joins outside the `IF` statement, which would allow it to refer to `oldC` and `newC` (or something analogous). Is this possible and how would the altered version of `p` look (with correct PostgreSQL syntax)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, there is no `NEW` in case of a `DELETE`, so `RETURN NEW;` doesn't make sense. This would raise an exception before Postgres 11, where this was [changed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.21.4):

> - In PL/pgSQL trigger functions, the `OLD` and `NEW` variables now read as NULL when not assigned (Tom Lane)
>
> Previously, references to these variables could be parsed but not
> executed.

It doesn't matter *what* you return for `AFTER` triggers anyway. Might as well be `RETURN NULL;`

There is no `OLD` in case of an `INSERT`, either.

You would only need a *single* trigger the way you have it right now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER a_i_u_d   -- *one* trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON a
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION p ();
```

**However**, I suggest ***separate trigger functions*** for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to avoid complications. Then you need three separate triggers, each calling its respective trigger function.

The case you want to add can *only* affect `UPDATE`. Nothing can "change" like you describe with `INSERT` or `DELETE`. And strictly speaking, what you ask for is *impossible* even for an `UPDATE` trigger:

> depending on a column `c2` in `c`: if that joined column changed ...

A trigger function on table `a` only sees a *single* snapshot of table `c`. There is no way to detect any "change" in that table. ***If*** you really meant to write:

> depending on column `a.a1`: if that changed so that the referenced value `c.c2` is different now ...

.. then there is a way:

Since a `BEFORE` trigger is less prone to endless loops and other complications, I demonstrate a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. (Changing to `AFTER` is trivial.):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_upbef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.a1 <> OLD.a1 THEN  -- assuming a1 is defined NOT NULL
      IF (SELECT count(DISTINCT c.c2) > 1  -- covers possible NULL in c2 as well
          FROM   c
          WHERE  c.c1 IN (NEW.a1, OLD.a1)) THEN
            -- do something
      END IF;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

If `a1` can be NULL and you need to track changes from / to NULL as well, you need to do more ...

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upbef
BEFORE UPDATE ON a
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION p_upbef ();
```

Since everything depends on a change in `a.a1` now (and you don't have other things in the trigger) you can move the outer `IF` to the trigger itself (cheaper):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_upbef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT count(DISTINCT c.c2) > 1  -- covers NULL as well
       FROM   c
       WHERE  c.c1 IN (NEW.a1, OLD.a1)) THEN  -- assuming a1 is NOT NULL!
      -- do something
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upbef
BEFORE UPDATE OF a1 ON a  -- !
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION p_upbef();
```

It's not *exactly* the same, since an `UPDATE` *involving* the column `a1` might actually leave the value unchanged , but it's good enough either way for our purpose: *to only run the expensive check on `c.c2` in relevant cases*.

Related:

- [How To Avoid Looping Trigger Calls In PostgreSQL 9.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663926/how-to-avoid-looping-trigger-calls-in-postgresql-9-2-1/13665973#13665973)
- [Cycloning in trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507123/cycloning-in-trigger/16512527#16512527)

Comment: +1 Is it correct to assume that I would have to place a/nother trigger on `c` to support the first interpretation ("depending on a column c2 in c: if that joined column changed")?

Comment: @Drux: Yes, to monitor changes in `c.c2` you need a trigger on `c`. Careful not to create endless loops with too many triggers. Sometimes, combined queries using data-modifying CTEs are a good alternative. [Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)